# HaxeFlixel: Custom Preloader not Working

Tags: haxe, openfl, haxeflixel

I am a beginner to HaxeFlixel and I would like to replace the default preloader. Instead of it displaying the standard HaxeFlixel logo, I would like it to display a "Loading..." message.

After extensive searching, the only useful resource I found was [this](https://gamepopper.co.uk/2014/08/26/haxeflixel-making-a-custom-preloader/). My problem is not with writing the preloader class, but instead getting HaxeFlixel to use my custom preloader.

From what I have found, this is how I would go about doing it (`Project.xml`):

```
<app preloader="MyLoader" />
```

Unfortunately, HaxeFlixel seems to completely ignore it. Is it maybe a bug with OpenFL?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all you could simply [disable HaxeFlixel splash screen](http://api.haxeflixel.com/flixel/FlxGame.html)

> new(GameSizeX:Int = 640, GameSizeY:Int = 480, ?InitialState:Class, Zoom:Float = 1, UpdateFramerate:Int = 60, DrawFramerate:Int = 60, SkipSplash:Bool = false, StartFullscreen:Bool = false)
>
> SkipSplash - Whether you want to skip the flixel splash screen in FLX_NO_DEBUG or not.

If you want use your custom preloader show your MyLoader class or upload minimal project somewhere to see

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for. Thank you!